# How can I make a div element inside a disabled fieldset enabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fieldset with a bunch of elements. It's disabled, but I want to keep one of the divs and all its children in the div enabled, while keeping all the other elements disabled. Is this possible? Either in JQuery or CSS or anything!

ex. I want to enable "Notes" but keep "Paper" disabled

```html
<fieldset disabled>
  <div name="paper" class="form-control" style="width:100%; height:300px;border:1px solid black;">
    <input name="AddPaper" type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" />
  </div>
  <div name="notes" class="form-control" style="width:100%; height:300px;border:1px solid black;">
    <input name="AddNotes" type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" />
    <input name="saveNotes" type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: When disable the parent, its children will be too. Move the disable to the children which need it

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it on the child, which you easily can toggle using jQuery or JS

```html
<fieldset>
  <div name="paper" class="form-control" style="width:100%; height:300px;border:1px solid black;">
    <input disabled name="AddPaper" type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" />
  </div>
  <div name="notes" class="form-control" style="width:100%; height:300px;border:1px solid black;">
    <input name="AddNotes" type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" />
    <input name="saveNotes" type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Or change markup

```css
fieldset fieldset {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <fieldset disabled>
    <div name="paper" class="form-control" style="width:100%; height:300px;border:1px solid black;">
      <input name="AddPaper" type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <div name="notes" class="form-control" style="width:100%; height:300px;border:1px solid black;">
      <input name="AddNotes" type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" />
      <input name="saveNotes" type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is to rearrange the disable attribute for all the elements except the one you have chosen:

```js
$(function () {
  $('fieldset:disabled').prop('disabled', false).children().each(function(i, e) {
    var jEle = $(e);
    if (jEle.attr('name') != 'notes') {
      jEle.find('*').prop('disabled', true).css('background', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<fieldset disabled>
    <div name="paper" class="form-control" style="width:100%; height:300px;border:1px solid black;">
        <input name="AddPaper" type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" />
    </div>
    <div name="notes" class="form-control" style="width:100%; height:300px;border:1px solid black;">
        <input name="AddNotes" type="button" value="Add" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" />
        <input name="saveNotes" type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```